# AutoCompleteView not wide enough

Tags: android, android-layout

I declared an AutoCompleteView with android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content". I was surprised to see that long strings within the drop-down list were truncated, and that the dropdown list was only as wide as the editText to which it is attached.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setDropDownWidth%28int%29) says that one uses "WRAP_CONTENT to fit the width of its anchor view". So wrap_content causes the width of the dropdown to match the width of the editText, not the longest string in the dropdown list.